# Ruby:-how to find the average of x and y axis

Tags: ruby

I am trying out the following code to find the average of x and y in a graph with the help of ruby.How ever I am getting nil as the output when I am running it.The below is the snippet of the code I am using.

```
class Point
        # Initialize our class variables
        @@n = 0              # How many points have been created
        @@totalX = 0         # The sum of all X coordinates
        @@totalY = 0         # The sum of all Y coordinates

        def initialize(x,y)  # Initialize method
          @x,@y = x, y       # Sets initial values

          # Use the class variables in this instance method
          @@n += 1           
          @@totalX += x      
          @@totalY += y
        end

        def report
          # Here we use the class variables
          puts "Number of points created: #@@n"
          puts "Average X coordinate: #{@@totalX.to_f/@@n}" # float
          puts "Average Y coordinate: #{@@totalY.to_f/@@n}"
        end
      end
```

Please suggest me how to find the average of x and y axis.

Comment: Maybe make report a class function?

Comment: Indeed, you should get `nil`. `puts` returns `nil` regardless of what it prints.

Comment: @sawa  what do I do to get the average of x and y axis

Comment: Minor complaint: how does that relate to Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the code and Im able to see the printed values. But the method returns nil. To make it return values, do this.

```
  def report
    # Here we use the class variables
    puts "Number of points created: #@@n"
    puts "Average X coordinate: #{@@totalX.to_f/@@n}" # float
    puts "Average Y coordinate: #{@@totalY.to_f/@@n}"
    return @@totalX, @@totalY
  end
```

Then you can do

```
x_total, y_total = Point.new(10, 8).report
```

**EDIT**

Please note that the return values are the Total. If you want to return averages, do this

```
return @@totalX.to_f/@@n, @@totalY.to_f/@@n
```

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to use 'return' in ruby?

Comment: I dont think so, but it is not required. In this particular case, `x, y` will give a syntax error. Another way to do this without using return is `[x, y]`

Answer (score -1):

You have defined report as an instance function. When I tested it I found that it would print the expected output if called against an instance of your class  e.g.:

```
p = Point.new(1,2)
p.report
```

It doesn't return a value though.  So if you tried calling it as:

```
v = p.report
```

You would get a nil value, which is what is returned by your puts statements.

I'm not sure if your problem is because the function returns nil, or because you are not calling it as an instance function.

If you want to define it as a class function change it to:

```
def self.report
```

Then you can call it as

```
Point.report
```

If you wanted your 'report' function to actually return something that you can use somewhere else then you need to make that the last thing that your function does.  Eg:

```
def self.average
   # Here we use the class variables
   Point.new(@@totalX.to_f/@@n,@@totalY.to_f/@@n)
end
```

Comment: This is just a suggestion that is irrelevant to the question's point. It is not answering the question at all. It could at best be a comment to the question. And the description "It works perfectly if you call it on one of your points" at the top is wrong, considering that the OP does not want `nil`.

Comment: OP stated that they got nil output, not nil returned.